# postscript with embedded logo eps file for printing a report

Tags: printing, postscript

I am trying to write a print report with postscript being the form design and the body of the report is dynamic data received from a database.
I need to include at least 2 eps files.

1, Being our customer logo, which has been converted to eps.
2, A postscript form design, basically a square box that fills the page
with a tail description at the bottom, which can be several lines.

it will also be nice if i can have a 3rd eps file which is almost identical to the 2nd eps file, but to specify the end of the report with some extra details at the tail end (bottom of the page).

The Basic flow of my program:
1. print header    -this will be the eps of logo
2. print data line from a database source

check for end of page?
No...... > loop back to print the next data line.
Yes......> print 2nd eps file

(print next page)
loop back to print header (1st eps file) and continues with the report
until end of report.

my issue is:
if I only use the logo eps, every page will print the logo header and works well.
But if I include the 2nd eps file,
the first page will print the logo and the boxing from the 2nd eps file correctly,
but subsequent pages will only print the boxing from the 2nd eps file, and no logo being printed.

this issue appears to occur whenever i use any logo image that has been converted to eps, so if i replace my 2nd eps with just another logo, only one logo will be printed, but if i write 2 postscript each with a box and 2 different tails, the report will print perfectly.

But if I only use the logo eps, that will also work well.

any suggestion please?

(sorry i was not able to include the postscript in question.....i kept getting error when i tried to past in my code).

but any simple postscript that draw a box and a few descriptive text 
and a logo that has been converted to an eps file will cause the issue.

Comment: Put the code somewhere public (eg DropBox) there's no practical way to determine the problem in a program without seeing the code. There can be many problems, eg a poorly constructed EPS file, or your handling of the EPS may be incorrect. We need to see **exactly** what your PostScript program contains.

Comment: Hi Kens thank you for the reply, i have now created dropbox it contain the two eps, well one eps (the image) and one the postscript that i have written (box with a footer description)

Comment: Going to need a link :-)

Comment: Hi KenS,  my comment has just been sent out without knowing, dropBox llink: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgjmb5xjvu93tz0/img1.eps?dl=0   and   https://www.dropbox.com/s/905xwuogjjcyvdt/psEps2.eps?dl=0,  i print to a device, for email device i use <esc2pdf> to convert my "print linage" to pdf and for printer device, i use <esc2ps>.... thus my work will always print a line at a time, first eps image header block, followed data from database followed by postscript file block to print the box followed by formfeed, then  the next page.. the image.eps (header block) and so forth.   kind regards

Comment: OK well I'm not sure I understand your problem. You've sent me 2 EPS files, but no PostScript program to use them. Are you aware of the differences between PostScript and Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) ? I really need to see precisely what you are sending to the printer, not just the components, but how you are assembling them

Comment: Hi KenS, it is literally a line print: ok more detail: line 1 <esc27>*!img1.eps<esc27>, send to printer device, text1 send to printer device...... text50 send to printer device, <esc27>*!psEps2.eps<esc27>  send to printer device issue formfeed, <esc27>*!img1.eps<esc27> send to printer device...etc.... the <esc27> =the ascii control character 27. the sent data is held in printer spooler (file ?) ... the spoller pips the file to esc2pdf (for pdf-email) or to esc2ps for a postscript printer device, once thats done, the output data is sent to the printer or emailed....does this make sense? cheers

Comment: I'm not clear on how you can use EPS with an epson printer, which is what you seem to be trying to do... Of course I don't know anything about esc2pdf or esc2ps either. So, I can't tell you anything about what is or might be incorrect based on what you've given me, because its not what you are sending to the (PostScript) printer. I'd need to see the **output** from esc2ps to be able to comment on what is going on. If the output of esc2ps (or esc2pdf for that matter) is incorrect, then you'll need to take it up with the authors of those tools.

Comment: ok i will try to intercept the output file tomorrow and will come back....hum are we allowed to continue with discussions in comments?....just got a message not to do so...ewww.... you are a great help KenS..never thought that there might well be an issue with esc2ps.

Comment: If you're adding information that's needed for the question, then it's usually better to edit the question to add the info. Then you can post a quick comment like `please see updated question`. Little comments can be cleaned-up later. But, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 0):

Hi KenS and everyone else who was following my question.
i have changed the way i have created the 2 eps.
i have generated the logo eps using GIMP as before.
but now, i have seen the code below from

---

### https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/graphics/import/sample/combined.html

this allows to combine more then one eps

after adding the defined code in the link above

each of our eps needs to start with:-

BeginEPSE
%%BeginDocument: (type the name for the following eps)

(your eps code )   in my case was the Form Box and tail

%%EndDocument

EndEPSE

BeginEPSE

%%BeginDocument:

<.... copy all the code for the logo  >

%%EndDocument

EndEPSE

this has solved my issue, I am sure my original method should still work...maybe with time??